# Oracle Stored Procedure Running Errors

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors, oracle10g

I am attempting my first stored procedure for Oracle because my previous insert statement wasn't working. I get these weird errors that I have been googling for hours on and no one seems to have corrections to my specific issue.

I just want to be able to add records :/

My code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Insert_classifieds 
 (val_date  IN      TABLENAME.Addate%type, 
  val_category    IN      TABLENAME.Category%type, 
  val_user    IN      TABLENAME.Username%type, 
  val_ phone  IN       TABLENAME.Phonenbr%type, 
  val_email  IN        TABLENAME.Email%type,
  val_shortDes  IN       TABLENAME.Description%type,
  val_longDes   IN      TABLENAME.Fulldescription%type ,
  val_newstandardid out TABLENAME.Classid%type
) 
as num_standardid number; 
begin  
    select t_class_seq.nextval into num_standardid from dual; 

    INSERT INTO TABLENAME (Classid, Addate, Category, Username, Phonenbr, Email, Description, Fulldescription)
    VALUES (num_standardid, val_date, val_category, val_user, val_phone, val_email, val_shortDes, val_longDes); 

    commit; 
    val_newstandardid := num_standardid; 
end;
```

Comment: Googling is admirable but when it comes to syntax errors your first port of call should always be [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was that val_phone had a space and a few touch up corrections.

final:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Insert_classifieds 
(val_date        TABLENAME.Addate%type,
  val_category         TABLENAME.Category%type, 
  val_user        TABLENAME.Username%type,  
  val_phone        TABLENAME.phonenbr%type,
  val_email         TABLENAME.Email%type,
  val_shortDes        TABLENAME.Description%type,
  val_longDes        TABLENAME.Fulldescription%type)  

as num_classid number; 

begin  

select t_class_seq.nextval into num_classid from dual;  

INSERT INTO TABLENAME (Classid, Addate, Category, Username, Phonenbr, Email, Description, Fulldescription) 
   values (num_classid, val_date, val_category, val_user, val_phone, val_email, val_shortDes, val_longDes);  

commit;  

end;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to create a procedure, the syntax is (you were missing the "PROCEDURE" Keyword):

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Insert_classifieds`

Comment: Of all the editing I have been doing to my code I must have removed that. It changes my errors now to stating my line using `.nextval` has `success with compilation`, my `value` line has error `column not allowed here` and my last 2 code lines are `invalid SQL statements` lol. Never ending! lol